# Normalize to sum to unity, but assign minimum value

Tags: normalization, threshold

I want to normalize some sample that I have to sum to unity:

$$
W = \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i
$$

$$
normalized_i = w_i/W
$$

However, it might happen that the values of `normalized` drop below 0.05 for some $w_i$. Whenever this is the case, I want to set the normalized value to 0.05. Is there a nice way of writing this down?
So far, I've (1) calculated `W` without the thresholding to 0.05, (2) thresholded all normalized values using the max(normalized, 0.05) operator, (3) calculated `W` again and (4) did the normalization again. This takes four equations though.
Is there a nice way to write this shorter?

The background/context for my question is the following:
I'm applying a sequential data assimilation scheme, which means I am using several noisy models to propagate the state of a system probabilistically in time. Each model has a certain amount of runs initially. The model-predicted state is updated with observations to obtain an optimal estimate for the system state. In the next cycle (propagate-update) the normalized weights shall determine with how many runs a model contributes to the next model-prediction of the state. "Good" (=closer to OBS) models shall get more runs, "bad" models less. However, "bad" models should not obtain no runs, otherwise they disappear from the ensemble. This is why `normalized_i` should not drop below 0.05, in this case.

Comment: I cannot fathom in what situation an algorithm of that nature might prove useful and it cannot cover all contingencies.  Suppose there are 25 entries all at exactly 0.04, what then? It might help if you explain what the goal is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! It's about model contributions to an overall ensemble result. These contributions come from some goodness measure (inverse distance of model prediction to observation), which needs to be normalized. However, I would like to ensure that all models have a minimum contribution to the ensemble and set a "contribution threshold" of 0.05.

Comment: The usual practice is to discard factors whose contribution to a model is not significant.

Comment: Ok, maybe I need to explain more: I'm applying a sequential data assimilation scheme, so models should not be "lost". If I get you correctly, this would be the case if I discard the factors, right?

Comment: Sequential data assimilation scheme. Does not ring a bell. Tell us what you are doing step by step, then we can tell you what's up with  it.

Comment: Tough to describe in short: I am using several noisy models to propagate the state of a system probabilistically in time. Each model has, say, 100 runs initially . The model-predicted state is updated with observations to obtain an optimal estimate for the system state. In the next cycle (propagate-update) the `normalized` weights shall determine with how many runs a model contributes to the next model-prediction of the state. "Good" (=closer to OBS) models shall get more runs, "bad" models less. However, "bad" models should not obtain no runs, otherwise they disappear from the ensemble.

Comment: So do some sort of running average and weight that.

Comment: Temporally running average? That actually sounds like a feasible idea. I will try that out!

Comment: OK, but fix your question up so that the other users on this site do not close it for lack of clarity. Simply enough just put in your comments adapted for the question, into the body of the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I did that.

Comment: Well, you could accept the answer, if you appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, I was still experimenting on the method...but it sound plausible to me!

Comment: Essentially, you needed an algorithm that remembers not to give up trying something just because in some cases that thing is not relevant, *ergo*, introduce memory into the algorithm. It's that simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is inconsistent to normalize at any particular fixed percentage like 5% for each factor. For example, for 25 factors, the average weight would be 4% such that reweighing is not possible while maintaining each factor >5%. However, what is being attempted is to introduce memory to an algorithm. One way to do that is to use a [running average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) of some type. For that, a cumulative, exponential, or weighted memory will never drop factors entirely. A simple moving average of the last $n$ trials can drop factors when $n>N$ and $N$ is the number of trials.